# Dictionary Assignment Not Functioning As Intended

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

CONTEXT

I'm creating a calculator. I'm at the point where I want my calculator to do BODMAS (start calculations with the inner most bracket).

The user enters an expression, in this example it is: `expression = (1+(1+1))`

I have a function that splits up this function into 'terms' and saves the result in `expression_list`.

`expression_list = ['(', '1', '+', '(', '1', '+', '1', ')', ')']`

I have a function that locates the indexes of all brackets in `expression_list` and saves it in `b_pairs`.

For the above expression the **intended** output for `b_pairs` should be of the form:

`b_pairs = [{'ob_1', 0}, {'ob_2', 3}, {'cb_1', 7}, {'cb_2', 8}]`

Here is the function:

```
for term in expression_list:
    if term == '(':
        b_pairs.append({"ob_"+str(ob),index})
        ob+=1
    elif term == ')':
        b_pairs.append({"cb_"+str(cb),index})
        cb+=1
    index+=1
```

Where `'ob'` represents an open bracket and `'oc'` represents a close bracket.

PROBLEM

The function works because it identifies the location of the open/close brackets and their respective locations correctly, but it mixes up the format. Here is the **actual** result:

`b_pairs = [{0, 'ob_1'}, {'ob_2', 3}, {'cb_1', 7}, {8, 'cb_2'}]`

Notice the order in (a) `b_pairs[0]` and (b) `b_pairs[1]`. I want the **key** to be the name of the bracket  and the **value** to be the location of the bracket in expression_array, e.g. {'ob_1,0}, not the other way around.

I've coded such that the format should be as in `b_pairs[1]`, but for some strange reason it's not always so.

I've debugged the code but I can't see any logical reason for this happening. I know that a dictionary with multiple key/value pairs will not always be printed in order, but in this example the dictionary variables in `expression_list` are single key/value and I code such that the key should be the name of the bracket, not the index of the bracket in `expression_list`. Please help.

Comment: This seems to be a set, not a dict.

Comment: It seems to me that you are not actually appending `dict`s, but rather appending `set`s. Try to change `, index` to `: index`

Comment: A dict item is formed by a `:` collon; just using commas creates a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re creating Sets, not Dicts. See below:

`a = {1, 2}`
This is a set containing 1 and 2.

`b = {1: 2}`
This is a dict where the value 2 is stored for the key 1.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issues. What an oversight.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.